# React.JS database connection

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, reactjs, jsx

I have login and sign up pages, and I tried to connect a mysql database to check login process (like checking email invalid or not) or add new users on signup page. But I couldn't connect to the database.  I also couldn't get a value from the textbox.

How can I solve these problems? Is there any way that I can make these connections easily, or a tutorial that I can learn from, or an example?

These are my pages

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');    

function success(data){
    alert('success');
}

function buttonClicked(){
    alert('success');        
}

function Welcome(){      
    alert('Welcome!!') ;
}

class Signup extends React.Component {           
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div id="signup">
                    <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="FirstName" />
                    <input type="text" id="lastName"  placeholder="LastName" />
                    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />    
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <input type="password" id="confirm" placeholder="PasswordConfirm" />
                    <button id="send" onClick ={buttonClicked} >Send</button>          
                </div>
            </div>
       )
    }
}


class Login extends React.Component {              
    render(){              
        return(
           <div>
               <div id="login">
                   <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />    
                   <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                   <button id="send" onClick ={Welcome}>Send</button>
               </div>
           </div>            
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use express.js api but i wrote this code on visual studio it is a .Net core web app but it didnt give permission to install some npm package and i install somethings  to solve some problems after that what i install broke another things.

Comment: You should use redux, redux-thunk and fetch for connecting to the .NET api.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i'll try it..